# How can I find the first entry of each day if i have a timestamp column as MM/DD/YY HH:MM as 24hours clock I'm excel using pandas/python/excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

My table has a timestamp column with entries of date in the format of MM/DD/YY HH:MM 24HOURS CLOCK.
I'm supposed to find the salesperson who does the first entry of each day using this column. I also need to save the first entries in a xlsx file as an output.

Comment: The table has multiple columns which also needs to be included in that query... So hopefully you can write a generalized query which targets the timestamp column and saves the whole row of first entry with it

Comment: I am afraid you misunderstand the purpose of SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your question accordingly. SO is not a free coding service where you post your tasks and receive a code in return. You have to ask a code-related question and get an answer specific to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Pandas library. You can use Pandas to search into a column and save the result as a CSV file. Could be something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Open the file:
pd = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# Search for specific range of date within the date column:
df = df[(df['date'] > '2022-01-01 00:00') & (df['date'] < '2022-02-01 00:00')]

# Save the result:
df.to_csv(index=False)
```